# Angular2 httpClient - How can you get the content body?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

Before I updated to `HttpClient`, I used the `Http` class and loaded data using the following code.

```
get(): Promise<Account> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    // do nothing for unauthorized user, as should be handles on component
    if (error.status != '401') {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error._body || error);
}
```

If the server errored with a 500, or 400 (validation) i could return the text from the server via my `.catch` handler.

Now I have updated to use the `HttpClient` and my code has changed to this

```
get(): Promise<Account> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Account>(this.apiUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    // do nothing for unauthorized user, as should be handles on component
    if (error.status != '401') {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error._body || error);
}
```

As you can see only the `get` method has changed, but now I cannot get the `_body` of the error response?

How can I get the body of the response like I did before?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: This simple code will give you the body 

`let body = error.text()`

Comment: `.text()` isnt a method on HttpErrorResponse

Comment: @Gillardo, did you do console log of the error object to see its structure?

Comment: Try with `error.json()`